# Android OAuth with valid "CONSUMER_KEY" and "CONSUMER_SECRET"

Tags: java, android, rest, http, oauth-2.0

I have a valid `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` for my app to access resources on a certain website.

I create the consumer like this:

```
private void createConsumer(){
    mConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
}
```

I create the provider like this:

```
private void createProvider(){
    mProvider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, 
                  AUTHORIZE_URL);
}
```

I then use an `AsyncTask` to retrieve what I assume is a valid `AccessToken` from the server.

```
mAccessTokenUrl = mProvider.retrieveRequestToeken(mConsumer, CALL_BACK_URL);
```

with this call I get something similar to this:
``http://www.mygarden.org/oauth/authorize?/oauth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXhs343sjd&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost

I'm assuming the token is correct because if I test this with the incorrect credentials I don't get anything back.

Question 1:

Is this `callback url` corrent, because on the site it does not specify a callback url, just the app's website; and how should I use it on the android app?

Question 2:

How do I now use the `Access Token` to consume certain services on the website, for example to get all the plants I should use this link: `http://api.mygarden.org/activities/all` which should return certain data in `xml/json` `format`

Extra information is that all calls to the API should use the `http GET` method unless specified otherwise. I do not want the user to first register on the site, I just want to consume the services they provide using my app's access credentials. If user credentials are necessary, could I embed them within the URL and grant the user access automatically?
The website is: http://www.mygarden.org

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of all the plants you don't need to authenticate a user. This is only necessary for user related actions, like posting status updates or adding plants to your garden.

So you only have to send a call to oauth/request_token and then oauth/access_token, after that you're ready to get some data from the API

Answer for Question 1:
If your developing an android application you don't need the callback url, this is needed when you want to authenticate a user trough a website. Make sure you select Client in the app settings on mygarden.org

Answer for Question 2:
To get all the plants you need plants/all. If you're using a standard oauth library, all the required oauth parameters are automatically added to your query

I'm a developer at mygarden.org, you can always contact our support ;)